# Python tornado encoding exception

Tags: python, tornado

I receive files by @tornado.web.stream_request_body decorator and save it.
But with one file if I try to download it, i receive exception:

`'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 42-47: ordinal not in range(256)`

in line 
`self.flush()` of tornado handler.

I see that data contain part as a `\x00word/_rels/document.xml.relsPK\x01\x02-\` (b"some data [this part]")
Maybe that's why an error occurs? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix problem. urlencode name of file in Content-Disposition header:

```
self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 
    'attachment; filename=' + urllib.parse.quote(file_name, safe=""))
```